# Find contributors to garbage in Java 21 or what replaces -XX:+PrintClassHistogram(Before|After)FullGC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

With Java 8 I occasionally used both, `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC` and  `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC` to get an impression about which classes contribute most to the garbage to be cleaned out.

Both options are gone at least since Java 17.

Is there a good or even better way to get a hint about the biggest garbage contributors with Java 17 or Java 21?